# difference between Data Extension types

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Can somebody please explain the differents of:

- Salesforce Data Extension
- Shared Salesforce Data Extension?
- Shared Data Extension

I cant find the definition on help.marketingcloud.com

Answer (score 0):

### Salesforce Data Extensions

Salesforce Data Extensions are Data Extensions that allow marketers to push tracking data back to their Sales or Service Cloud Orgs. The following pre-requisites apply:

1. Must include 18 digit Salesforce Contact or Lead ID to map to subscriber key.
2. Must have Email field set to the type of email address.
3. Field names cannot contain ? or % characters.

Refer to [Salesforce Data Extensions](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/key_concepts/salesforce_data_extension/) documentation for futher information.

### Shared Salesforce Data Extensions

These are similar to Salesforce Data Extensions, but they exist in (i.e. have been moved to) the Shared Salesforce Data Extensions folder.

A Shared Data Extension enables the Data Extension to be available in other Business Units. Furthermore, discrete permissions can be defined for each Business Unit in the account from the 'Permissions' tab enabling you to define the different type of permissions and timeframe window that the Data Extension is available in the Business Unit.

[image: Editing Data Extension Permissions]

### Shared Data Extensions

Similar to 'Shared Salesforce Data Extensions'. Once a DE has been moved to the Shared Data Extensions folder, discrete permissions can be defined for each Business Unit in the account from the 'Permissions' tab so the Data Extension is available in other Business Units.